# How to delete data which table has data in pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have a many to many relation ship, **User** and **Role**, I know I can delete data with detach function like

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->roles()->detach();
```

I can't delete role if it has data in role_user table, I tried

```
$user = User::all();
$user->roles()->detach();
```

It's not work, is there any easy way to do that or I just need to create **RoleUser** model and delete data in pivot before delete role?

Comment: Have you tried using the sync? [sync] (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models). single element is used for 'detach()' function.

Comment: can you write your models? mabe there is the problem.

Comment: I don't think `$user->roles()->detach();` is possible because you need to specify first the `user_id` which is defined when you execute `$user= User::find(1);`

Answer (score -1):

many to many tables with pivot (`USER_POSITION`)

`USER <-> USER_POSITION <-> POSITION`

```
User::find(1)->position()->detach(Position::find(1));
```